# How do I sleep a dedicated python thread for task scheduling?

Tags: python, multithreading, function, scheduled-tasks, sleep

I'm writing a library that will connect to sockets and manage them, process its data, and do stuff based on that.

My problem lays on sending b"\r\n\x00" to the socket every 20 seconds. I thought that if I started a new thread for the ping function, that would work.

..however, time.sleep() seems to pause the whole entire program instead of what I thought would be just that thread.

here's my code thus far:

```
def main(self):
  recvbuf = b""
  self.connect(self.group, self.user, self.password)
  while self.connected:
    rSocket, wSocket, error = select.select([x[self.group] for x in self.conArray], [x[self.group] for x in self.conArray], [x[self.group] for x in self.conArray], 0.2) #getting already made socket connections
    for rChSocket in rSocket:
      while not recvbuf.endswith(b"\x00"): #[-1] doesnt work on empty things... and recvbuf is empty.
        recvbuf += rChSocket.recv(1024) #need the WHOLE message ;D
      if len(recvbuf) > 0:
        dataManager.manage(self, self.group, recvbuf)
        recvbuf = b""
    for wChSocket in wSocket:
      t = threading.Thread(self.pingTimer(wChSocket)) #here's what I need to be ran every 20 seconds.
      t.start()
  x[self.group] for x in self.conArray.close()
```

and here's the pingTimer function:

```
def pingTimer(self, wChSocket):
  time.sleep(20)
  print(time.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p]")+"Ping test!") #I don't want to mini-DDoS, testing first.
  #wChSocket.send(b"\r\n\x00")
```

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
t = threading.Thread(self.pingTimer(wChSocket))
```

Does not do what you expect. It calls `self.pingTimer` in the same thread and passes the return value to `threading.Thread`. That's not what you want. You probably want this:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=self.pingTimer, args=(wChSocket,))
```

Comment: I had tried that but then it literally froze python followed by arch linux. I got the error "Can't start thread" and then it continued to run somehow by displaying a bunch of "Ping test!" then nothing responded except the mouse resulting in a forced reboot that I had to do.

Comment: @user2216833: I'm guessing that `select` didn't block and it got into an infinite loop creating as many threads as possible. That does indeed tend to strain the operating system a bit. I'd try figuring out *why* select wasn't blocking; once it blocks, I'm almost certain you'll have no problem with this.